# Eliminar palabras repetidas en una misma celda para realizar análisis de texto

Tags: pandas, dataframe, eliminar, repetidos

Como puedo en Python lograr que dentro de una misma celda se eliminen las palabras repetidas, de tal manera que al hacer un análisis de texto no se sobredimensionen las palabras duplicadas.

Ejemplo:
En el dataframe hay una columna llamada Asunto

1. El día de ayer sucedió un accidente de carro en el barrio San Francisco, el accidente no dejo heridos graves.

Quisiera que la frase quedara solo sin palabras duplicadas:

1. El día de ayer sucedió un accidente carro en barrio San Francisco, no dejo heridos graves.

Luego de esto, conozco como realizar el análisis de texto y un wordcloud pero primero tengo que limpiar la data para que funcione correctamente el resultado.

Comment: Saludos, en SOes no hacemos tareas ni exámenes, por favor [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/601794/edit) y agrega lo que has intentado hasta el momento. ;)

Comment: Buen día, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Es desmotivante entrar en una publicación con la intención de ayudar y ver que el usuario no ha mostrado que ha investigado o intentado algo. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que tienes hasta el momento y los errores que recibes, o en su defecto mostrar lo que has investigado. El objetivo de este sitio es ayudar a las personas que muestran un esfuerzo por resolver sus propias preguntas. Si la solicitud es del tipo alguien hágalo por mi, tal vez un sitio de `freelance` sea mejor opción.